# Where can I find a database of US colleges and the classes they offer?

Tags: database

I noticed that http://getchabooks.com has a list of many schools and the classes that they offer. Does anyone know how they get this data? I assume it's through some database, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Scraping college bookstore website chains, which provide a list of all the schools they run bookstores for.  See http://bncollege.com, http://efollett.com, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely through a database.  *Their* database to be precise and I doubt they will let you have access to it.

I found this site which looks pretty legit and offers a CSV or an excel for all accredited Colleges:

http://ope.ed.gov/accreditation/GetDownloadFile.aspx

The site does have the disclamer:

> The U.S. Department of Education cannot, therefore, guarantee that the
>   information contained in the database is accurate, current, or
>   complete.

You could probably come up with a scraper to glean the rest of the information from publicly available sites but you would have to check into the legality of that.

It's not everything but it's a start.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Tons and tons of manual data entry, and/or negotiations with the specific colleges they support. Not all colleges even have their **own** databases of classes (and most don't have book information online in any consistent format); there's certainly no central college course catalog database out there.